# Prepared query, erroneous # of variables != # of parameters error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-like

MySQL is beginning to drive me crazy. Almost every time I get an error, the description of the error thrown is completely different from the mistake that caused the error.

In this case, I'm trying to do the following:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT tag_name 
                              FROM tags 
                              WHERE tag_name LIKE '?%';");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$tag_string);
```

The MySQL query itself works fine when executed manually, but when I try to bind values dynamically in above I get the following error:

```
Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement
```

Which isn't true. Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot concatenate it like that because placeholder holds a place for the complete value, not its part.

The correct query would look like

```
... LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Like I figured, that had nothing to do with the actual error message thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
WHERE tag_name LIKE '?%';");
```

To this

```
WHERE tag_name LIKE ?");
```

Comment: So you're thinking `%` is optional there and can be just omitted?